# Remote Desktop client

Tags: remote-desktop

How do I access my desktop on my iPhone via Remote Desktop client. Can I access it through an ad hoc connection. I tried to connect via an ad hoc connection but it didn't work, I'm not sure if I'm getting the process right.

Comment: I use an app (client) called Mocha RDP lite and have no problems whatsoever...

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found a couple applications work really well for this. VNC works great. We use it at work, it's a little complicated if you're not familiar with networking. TeamViewer in my opinion works great! You literally just install and go. It's free and the security behind is pretty decent. I use it in my house.